# C# WinForms Text size issue (actually cant understand the result)

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, fonts

As a part of a bigger project I wrote the terminal emulator. Everything work file except one problem. I do not understand the connection between the values properties of the font (size) and screen pixels.

## Font

```
        TermFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, fsize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Tested with another units as well.

## number of characters I can display (both methods and both do not work).

```
        //FontSizef = tg.MeasureString(testString, TermFont);
        //int xchars = (int)(p.Width / FontSizef.Width) + 1;
        //int ychars = (int)(p.Height / FontSizef.Height);
        int xchars = (int)(p.Width / TermFont.Size) + 1;
        int ychars = (int)(p.Height / TermFont.Height);
```

The first measuring method (commented). I measure the size of the one character string. As it is monospaced font all letters should have the same size. Tested both methods. Result is exactly the same.

## The problem

It is giving me too low number of characters
So it looks like this:
[image]

Probably I do not understand how the unit system works.

Help appreciated ::
[image]

Comment: See the "Remarks" section in [Graphics.MeasureString Method (String, Font)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Use `Points` when you're defininig a Font properties. The unit conversion is performed by the measuring tool. I assume `tg` here means something like Terminal Graphics, a Graphics derived from the *container* context. But it's unclear how this graphics contex is obtained. If that is a `RichTextBox` or a `TextBox` control, use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wafk2kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to derive the Pixel size of a string in a specific graphics context. 1 Point = 1 Pixel at 72 Dpi `->` the actual context is more than relevant. The format flags do the rest.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you very much. I naively thought that monospaced font is glyph free :)

Comment: @Jimi it is my user control.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It has a a device context as everything else you can write/paint on. Same considerations.